# releasing memory allocated for char* in C

Tags: c, memory-management

Can someone, please, explain to me, what is wrong in my code below?
As I understand it, I need to release memory allocated for char* - or it will leak it. However, if I use (at the very end of the program free(), I am getting:
malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff7274027a4: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

without "free()" this code runs just fine and gives me what I need.
Thank you in advance!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

  int main ()
 {
    char *src="start=3.6307436653491267,2.2931731236906048,0";
    char *psrc;
    psrc=calloc((strlen(src)+1),sizeof(char));
    strcpy(psrc,src);
    size_t len= strlen(src);
    len +=1;
    char str[len];
    int count=0;
    char *wt=calloc(3,sizeof(char));
    char *ft=calloc(17, sizeof(char));
    char *finalstr=calloc((strlen(wt) + strlen(ft) + 1), sizeof(char));
    while (psrc != NULL && *psrc != '\0' && count <= len)
    {
        if(psrc[0] == '=')
        {
            psrc +=1;
            strcpy(str, psrc);
            wt=strtok(str, ".");
            ft=strtok(NULL, ".");
            ft=strtok(ft, ",");
            strcpy(finalstr, wt);
            strcat(finalstr, ".");
            strncat(finalstr, ft, 2);
        }
        ++psrc;
        ++count;
   }
   printf("finalstr: %s\n", finalstr);
   //free(psrc);
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that. but my question is different.

Comment: No, you should fix all that. Your code has undefined behavior, whether you `free()` or not is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: You have to free the exact pointer that was returned by `malloc` etc.  In your case, you have modified the pointer by adding to it.

Comment: You `malloc()` `ft`, `wt` and others and then reassign them, THAT'S EXACTLY A MEMORY LEAK.

Comment: You write out of bounds of the block pointed to by `finalstr` (which has size 1)

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi `calloc(x,y)` is defined as allocating `x*y` bytes, so it is not possible to have the arguments "in the wrong order"

Comment: In fact they were in the correct order, I don't use `calloc()` often. But they can be in the wrong order. It's `calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)`

Comment: so, would it be then a solution to this to use realloc to obtain correct address for changed pointer? and then free it up?

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you can only pass to `free()` a pointer that was returned by `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()` and you are passing the incremented `psrc`.

For example,

```
char *string = malloc(SIZE);
free(string + 1);
```

is undefined behavior, the only acceptable and correct way to call `free()` would be

```
free(string);
```

and you have

```
psrc += 1;
```

which changes the value of `psrc` and it no longer points to the address originally returned by `calloc()`.

Although if you are worried about a memory leak you need to understand them.

In your code, you have

```
char *wt = calloc(3, sizeof(char));
```

and then,

```
wt = strtok(str, ".");
```

*That's exactly a memory leak*: Because you now can't `free()` the memory earlier returned by `calloc()`.

You need to study *pointers* before you continue, it doesn't make a lot of sense to worry about memory leaks when you have a explicit memory leak in your code and yet you don't know.

I also think that you should reconsider the following statement

> without "free()" this code runs just fine and gives me what I need.

The code will not always *give you what You need*, because it has severe bugs that will cause **undefined behavior**, so it's *IMPOSSIBLE* to predict the result anyway.

If you carefully read documentation for the functions used in the below example, you would right the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *src = "start=3.6307436653491267,2.2931731236906048,0";
    const char *equal;
    char *endptr;
    float value;
    int length;
    char *result;

    // Find the equal sign, if not found the function
    // returns and no output is shown
    equal = strchr(src, '=');
    if (equal == NULL)
        return -1;
    // Convert the string to a `float' starting
    // at the `=' sign and up to the `,'
    value = strtof(equal + 1, &endptr);
    // If the first non numeric character wasn't a `,'
    // then this input string is not as we expected it to
    // be so we abort the program.
    if (*endptr != ',')
        return -1;
    // Create a string from the number, with just 2
    // decimal places.

    // Compute the length of the resulting string
    length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.2f", value);
    if (length == -1)
        return -1;
    // Allocate space for it
    result = malloc(length + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return -1;
    // Finally "print" the number into the string
    snprintf(result, length, "%.2f", value);
    // Now we have the string we wanted
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", result);
    // After we've done our work with `result' then we
    // have to `free()' it
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I appreciate your efforts, but, I am specifically avoiding treating "numbers" in that string as numbers (whether it is float or double or whatever). I want them to be strings and that's why all these dances with pointers to char.

Comment: Use `snprintf()` with the number.

Comment: thank you again. I am not interested in numbers as a collection of digits. at all. this is just a small part of program which reads text file and forms ngc file (for cnc machine) out of it.

Answer (score 0):

`psrc`is no longer pointing to its original address. You might want to add `psrc -= count;` just before freeing the memory.

Comment: Right idea although `count` is not the right amount to move by

Comment: ok. I am being criticized for saying "answer" and not providing it.

Comment: ok. I am being criticized for saying "answer" and not providing one. so, here is another version of my horrible C coding. Could you please express your opinions on it?

Comment: kinda difficult to post what is needed... :(

Comment: char *truncnum(const char *original, unsigned int precision)
{ 
  char *psrc=calloc((strlen(original) + 1),sizeof(char));
  strcpy(psrc,original);
  char *wt=calloc(10,sizeof(char));
  char *ft=calloc(precision +1, sizeof(char));
  char *finalstr=calloc((strlen(wt) + strlen(ft) + 1), sizeof(char));
  unsigned int count=0;
  unsigned int count2=0;
  while (psrc != NULL && *psrc != '\0' && count <= strlen(psrc) && count2 <=precision)
  {
    if (count2 == precision)
    {
      break;
    }
    if(psrc[count] == '=')
    {
      count +=1;

Comment: unsigned int len=strlen(&psrc[count]) +1;
      char *tmp=calloc(len,sizeof(char));
      if(strncpy(tmp, &psrc[count],1) == 0)
      {
        printf("error coping to tmp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      strcpy(wt, tmp);
      free(tmp);
      count +=2;
strncpy(ft,&psrc[count],1);
      finalstr=strcpy(finalstr, wt);
      finalstr=strcat(finalstr,".");
      while(count2<precision)
      {
        strncat(finalstr,&psrc[count], 1);
        ++count;

Comment: ++count;
        ++count2;
      }
    }
    ++count;
  }
   return finalstr;
 free(psrc);
   psrc=NULL;
   free(wt);
   wt=NULL;
   free(ft);
   ft=NULL;
   free(finalstr);
   finalstr=NULL;